# SQL like syntax using date YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-like

I've been given part of a project financial reporting system to work on. Basically, I'm trying to modify an existing query to restrict returned results by date in a field which contains a variable date format.

My query is being sent the date from someone elses code in the format YYYY twice, so e.g. 2014 and 2017. In the SQL query below they are listed as 2014 and 2017, so you'll just have to imagine them as variables..

The fields in the database which have the variable date forms come in two forms: YYYYMMDD or YYYYMM.

The existing query looks like:

```
SELECT   
                    'Expense' AS Type,
                    dbo.Department.Description AS [Country Name],
                    dbo.JCdescription.Description AS Project,
                    dbo.Detail.AccountCode AS [FIN Code], 
                    dbo.JCdescription.ReportCode1 as [Phase Date Start], 
                    dbo.JCdescription.ReportCode2 as [Phase Date End], 
                    dbo.JCdescription.ReportCode3 as [Ratification Date], 
                    dbo.Detail.Year AS [Transaction Year], 
                    dbo.Detail.Period AS [Transaction Year Period], 
                    ...
                FROM
                    dbo.Detail
                INNER JOIN
                    ...
                WHERE
                    (dbo.Detail.LedgerCode = 'jc')
                ...
                AND
                    (dbo.Detail.Year) BETWEEN '2014 AND 2017";
```

Ideally I'd like to change the last line to:

```
(dbo.JCdescription.ReportCode2 LIKE '[2014-2017]%')
```

BUT this searches for all the digits 2,0,1,4,5 instead of everything between 2014 and 2017.

I'm sure I must be missing something simple here, but I can't find it! I realise I could rephrase it as `LIKE '201[4567]%'` but this means searches outside of 2010-2020 will error.. and requires me to start parsing the variables sent which will introduce an additional function which will be called a lot. I'd rather not do it. I just need the two numbers, 2014 and 2017 to be treated as whole numbers instead of 4 digits!

Running on MS SQL server 10.0.5520

Comment: Is your ReportCode2 a VARCHAR?

Comment: What is the issue with the existing code?

Comment: 1) The list of characters in square brackets is a character set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx -- what you're missing right there is any meaningful effort to find out what `like` means before asking SO why it inexplicably behaves precisely as documented. 2) Why do you want to use `like` for date range checking anyhow? `between @begin and @end` is correct. 3) As a general rule: Don't try to invent new clever ways to do obvious things. Master the basics before trying to revolutionize the profession.

Comment: ReportCode2 is VARCHAR - but the expected format is an INT which can either be 6 or 8 digits long.

Comment: The existing code works fine - but we need to search on a diferent field - the ReportCode1. This gives us more meaningful results. 

@EdPlunkett I'm totally open to exploring something other than 'LIKE' - my question is less around date checking and more around checking between a range of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use the [**year**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) system function if your date columns are any of the given [**date** or **datetime** data types available in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186724.aspx).

This would allow you to write something that looks pretty much like the following.

```
where year(MyDateColumn) between 2014 and 2017
```

Besides, if you're using [**varchar**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms176089.aspx) as the date column data type, you will have to [**cast**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) them to the appropriate and comparable values, and you'll also have to make sure to get the only required [**substring**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) you need for the comparison.

So let's suppose you have string value like '201505' in your `dateStringColumn`.

```
where cast(substring(dateStringColumn, 1, 4) as int) between 2014 and 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

So from my understanding you have 2 parameters for the start and end years that should be used to filter results.

With dates either being `YYYYMM` or `YYYYMMDD`, you can use string manipulation to take the first 4 characters and convert it to an `INT`, which can then be used to compare to the parameters.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #detail ( id INT , SomeDate NVARCHAR(10) )
INSERT  INTO #detail
        ( id, SomeDate )
VALUES  ( 1, '201311' ),
        ( 2, '201402' ),
        ( 3, '20140313' ),
        ( 4, '201409' ),
        ( 5, '201506' ),
        ( 6, '20150912' ),
        ( 7, '201612' ),
        ( 8, '201701' ),
        ( 9, '20181212' )

DECLARE @startYear INT = 2014, @endYear INT = 2017

SELECT *, CONVERT(INT, (LEFT(SomeDate, 4))) AS [Year]
FROM #detail
WHERE CONVERT(INT, (LEFT(SomeDate, 4))) BETWEEN @startYear AND @endYear 

DROP TABLE #detail
```

Based on the sample data, this would produce:

```
id  SomeDate    Year
====================
2   201402      2014
3   20140313    2014
4   201409      2014
5   201506      2015
6   20150912    2015
7   201612      2016
8   201701      2017
```

(excludes rows 1 & 9)

Answer (score 0):

use.[DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
datepart(year,dbo.Detail.Year) BETWEEN 2014 AND 2017;
```

Comment: as `DATEPART` returns an integer, you probably don't want to test for string values

Comment: i didn't notice because i think DATEPART is the main solution.btw thanks again